# Evaluating array content (PHP, XenForo)

Tags: php, arrays, xenforo

I'm having few troubles when evaluating an array data to filter some content. I'm sending to the template an array with few numbers (1,4,5,10,12,14,20 - for example) and then i want to filter if it has a specific value.

Let's say i want to know if it has '2' as a single value. What would be the best method?

I was using (strpos ($array, '2') !== false) but then i noticed that it checks if 2 is inside the array and not if it's just '2', so it returned true.

I need to be able to evaluate if '2' is specified as '2' and not if it's on the array string (like on '20' or '12').

PS: Although using xenforo(zend), any answer on php should be enough.

Hope you can help,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know whether value is in array:

> [in_array($needle, $haystack)](http://php.net/manual/pl/function.in-array.php)

If you want to get all values having given value:

> [array_filter($haystack, $filteringFunction)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

I'm stupid, thanks.

Let's switch to evaluate a string (just checked it, it's read as string and not array).

If i have $string ("9, 1, 2, 20, 14") and i want to evaluate that, if '2' is part of the string as "2" (again, the 2 from 20 isn't valid).

There's any way to do that without doing an explode? (Can't be used inside XF templates).

Sorry for my mistake.

Regards